# Arraylists and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have 2 arraylists situated inside an array as follows:

```
public Object[] loopthrougharrays() {
    Object[] tables = new Object[2];
    tables[0] = list;
    tables[1] = listB15;
    return tables;
}
```

My 2 arraylists are called `list` and `listB15`.

I can then call my arraylists from another method like

```
loopthrougharrays()[1] = new ArrayList();
```

which is `listB15`.

However if I try to add an item to the `ArrayList` like

```
loopthrougharrays()[1].add(s)
```

where `s` is a variable

Java doesn't recognize the `loopthrougharrays()[1]` as an `ArrayList`.

How can I add the variable via this method?

I appear to get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My entire code works fine if I do the following:

```
listB15 = new ArrayList();
listB15.add(s)
```

as I would expect.

Comment: You have an array of `Object`, how should the compiler know what instances it contains? And btw: you get the NPE because `loopthrougharrays()` creates a new array and that doesn't care about your `loopthrougharrays()[1] = new ArrayList();` statement.

Comment: tl;dr: make `tables` an `ArrayList[]` (or even better a `List[]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are doing assignments on method calls.
You are calling the method two times.
so the second line creates another array list

```
loopthrougharrays()[1] = new ArrayList();
loopthrougharrays()[1].add(s)  //This one will call the method again
// and get new array list and the previous value is lost
```

Simple fix

```
 Object[] getTwoArrays =  loopthrougharrays()
 ArrayList L0 = <ArrayList> getTwoArrays[0];
 ArrayList L1 = <ArrayList> getTwoArrays[1];

 L1 = new ArrayList();
 L1.add(s);
```

Here the loopthrougharrays() is called once and the return value is stored into a local reference and then it works

While I try to provide a quick fix provided, i would not return null arraylits in a object array and then initialize outside the method and do assignments. it's clumsy.

A lesser evil way is

```
 class SomeX {
    private List Ll = new ArrayList();
    private List L2  = new ArrayList();
    public addToL1(Object s) {
        L1.add(s);
    }
    public addToL2(Object s) {
        L2.add(s)
    }
 }

 //main method
 SomeX x = new SomeX();
 x.addToL1(s);
 x.addToL2(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what do you want to do with that, but it is not a good practice. However it could work, if you cast your Object array element to an ArrayList like:

```
((ArrayList)t.loopthrougharrays()[1]).add(s);
```

And delete `loopthrougharrays()[1] = new ArrayList();` (like @Tom comment says, thanks) or replace it with

```
ArrayList myNewArrayList = (ArrayList)loopthrougharrays()[1];
myNewArrayList.add(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast it before you add anything to your list.

```
((ArrayList<YourVariableType>)(loopthrougharrays()[1])).add(s);
```

But remember, this is not a good practice. I'm pretty sure, you can achieve what you want to achieve with a better design and with best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Your tables is an array of objects ,

`tables[1] = listB15;` // tables still remains as `array of object` and listB15 is considered as an object since `Object is the Super class` .

To achieve wt u want you can try these methods :

1. `((List<String>) tables[1]).add("hello world"); // cast it with List<String> (for example)`
2. create a list

   ```
   List<List<String>> tables = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

       tables1.add(list) ; 
       tables1.add(listB15) ; 

       tables1.get(1).add("hello world");
       System.out.println(tables);
   ```